# How do I drop all rows after last occurrence of a value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a string column and I would like to drop all rows after the last occurrence of a name.

```
first_name
Andy
Josh
Mark
Tim
Alex
Andy
Josh
Mark
Tim
Alex
Andy
Josh
Mark
```

What I would like is to drop rows after Alex occurs for the last time, so drop the rows with Andy, Josh and Mark.

I figured I drop before the first occurrence with: `df=df[(df.first_name== 'Alex').idxmax():]`, but don't know how to drop last rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

#### `argmax`

```
df.iloc[:len(df) - (df.first_name.to_numpy() == 'Alex')[::-1].argmax()]

  first_name
0       Andy
1       Josh
2       Mark
3        Tim
4       Alex
5       Andy
6       Josh
7       Mark
8        Tim
9       Alex
```

---

#### `last_valid_index`

```
df.loc[:df.where(df == 'Alex').last_valid_index()]
```

---

#### Option 3

```
df.loc[:df.first_name.eq('Alex')[::-1].idxmax()]
```

---

#### Option 4

```
df.iloc[:np.flatnonzero(df.first_name.eq('Alex')).max() + 1]
```

---

#### Option 5

This is silly!

```
df[np.logical_or.accumulate(df.first_name.eq('Alex')[::-1])[::-1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `mask` and `bfill`

```
df[df['first_name'].mask(df['first_name'] != 'Alex').bfill().notna()]

  first_name
0       Andy
1       Josh
2       Mark
3        Tim
4       Alex
5       Andy
6       Josh
7       Mark
8        Tim
9       Alex
```

---

### `cumsum` and `idxmax`

```
df.loc[:(df['first_name'] == 'Alex').cumsum().idxmax()]

  first_name
0       Andy
1       Josh
2       Mark
3        Tim
4       Alex
5       Andy
6       Josh
7       Mark
8        Tim
9       Alex
```

---

### `cumsum` and `max`

```
u = (df['first_name'] == 'Alex').shift().cumsum()
df[u < u.max()]

  first_name
1       Josh
2       Mark
3        Tim
4       Alex
5       Andy
6       Josh
7       Mark
8        Tim
9       Alex
```